# How does it know when string ends without a terminator? (Code below)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm learning MIPS on MARS and I am confused as per the following code. Because when I load an inputted string into a reserved space, the code outputs normally, even without a terminator. Why is this?
I thought every string needed a terminator so the input buffer knows when to stop.
Is there one filled in automatically or ...? Thanks in advance.
Code is:

```
# Filename: mips3.asm
# Author: me
# Program to read a string from a user, and
# print that string back to the console.
.data
prompt:     .asciiz "Please enter a string: "
output:     .asciiz "\nYou typed the string: "
input:      .space 81       # Reserve 81 bytes in Data segment
inputSize:  .word 80        # Store value as 32 bit word on word boundary
                        # A word boundary is a 4 byte space on the
                        # input buffer's I/O bus.
# Word:
    # A Word is the number of bits that can be transferred
    # at one time on the data bus, and stored in a register
    # in mips a word is 32 bits, that is, 4 bytes.
    # Words are aways stored in consecutive bytes,
    # starting with an address that is divisible by 4

.text
# Input a string.
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

# Read the string.
li $v0, 8           # Takes two arguments
la $a0, input       # arg1: Address of input buffer
lw $a1, inputSize   # arg2: Maximum number of characters to read
syscall

# Output the text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, output
syscall

# Print string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, input
syscall

# Exit program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Explicit-length strings are fine as long as you don't try to pass them to a function or syscall that that doesn't take a length (and instead looks for a terminator).  i.e. that takes an implicit-length C string.  Unfortunately the traditional read-string SPIM system call that MARS inherited is dumb and doesn't return the number of bytes read.  But the read-from file (`fread`) call does do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MARS documentation for syscalls:

> ... Service 8 — Follows semantics of UNIX `fgets`.  For specified length `n`, the input string from the user can be no longer than `n-1`.  If the input string is less than that, this syscall adds newline to end. *In either case, this syscall pads with null byte.* ...

So, in your case, any input string of 78 bytes or less gets both a newline and a null terminator.

---

The newline is a pain as we often don't want it.

On another note, the `.space 81` will be zeros upon program load, so the after the first syscall you will see zero padded to the end, but a second to the same area will not necessarily (i.e. if input was shorter), so the null termination behavior of syscall#8 is useful, and necessary — particularly since the service does not return the length of the input!

---

Also, note that MARS has documentation available in a menu item:

Help menu ↪ MIPS tab → Syscall subtab

There is some other interesting material/information at the Help menu as well.