# a function compare 2 string in mips

Tags: compare, mips

this function should simply verify if the input is equal to the string simolo1
even if I input exactly the same string the output is strings are not equal.

I am saving in the registers s2 and s3 the pointers to the arrays. then I compare each byte, if all of those are equal the program should finish and output 'strings are equal'

```
    .data
prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter string ('.' to end) > "
dot:        .asciiz     "."
eqmsg:      .asciiz     "strings are equal\n"
nemsg:      .asciiz     "strings are not equal\n"

str1:       .space      80
str2:       .space      80
simbolo1:   .asciiz     "sasso"
simbolo2:   .asciiz     "carta"
simbolo3:   .asciiz "forbice"
    .text

    .globl  main
main:
    # get first string
    la      $s2,str1
    move    $t2,$s2
    jal     getstr
    la      $s3, simbolo1
    
# string compare loop (just like strcmp)
cmploop:
    lb      $t2,($s2)                   # get next char from str1
    lb      $t3,($s3)                   # get next char from str2
    bne     $t2,$t3,cmpne               # are they different? if yes, fly

    beq     $t2,$zero,cmpeq             # at EOS? yes, fly (strings equal)

    addi    $s2,$s2,1                   # point to next char
    addi    $s3,$s3,1                   # point to next char
    j       cmploop

# strings are _not_ equal -- send message
cmpne:
    la      $a0,nemsg
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    j       main

# strings _are_ equal -- send message
cmpeq:
    la      $a0,eqmsg
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    j       main

# getstr -- prompt and read string from user
#
# arguments:
#   t2 -- address of string buffer
getstr:
    # prompt the user
    la      $a0,prompt
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # read in the string
    move    $a0,$t2
    li      $a1,79
    li      $v0,8
    syscall

    # should we stop?
    la      $a0,dot                     # get address of dot string
    lb      $a0,($a0)                   # get the dot value
    lb      $t2,($t2)                   # get first char of user string
    beq     $t2,$a0,exit                # equal? yes, exit program

    jr      $ra                         # return

# exit program
exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: What do you see when you debug it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69104011/471129

Comment: the function actually compare each byte. and the bytes are all equal. at the end of the string even though it was all equal until then, they become different. the link you sent is probably the problem. but I don't quite get how to fix it. my intention is to input "sasso.' and I want it to be equal to simbolo1

Comment: Right, but "sasso.", "sasso", and "sasso\n" are all different, so if your string compare works properly it will report them as different.

Comment: I changed simbolo1 to  "sasso./n", and now it works